# Adding half a month with lubridate

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

I want to add multiple steps of halfe a month with lubridate

```
for (i in range) {
  if(i%%2==1){
    day(dateseq[i]) <-  day(15)
  }
  if (i%%2==0) {
    dateseq[i] <- ceiling_date(dateseq[i-1], unit='month')
  }
}
```

but i think there should be a more  efficent way to do that

Edit:
the basic technique should work like this

```
dateseq <- as_datetime(rep.int(ymd_hms("2016-11-01_3-50-23"),15))
range <- 1:15
for (i in range) {
  if(i%%2==1){
    day(dateseq[i]) <-  15
  }
  if (i%%2==0) {
    dateseq[i] <- ceiling_date(dateseq[i-1])
  }
}
```

So it jumps between the 15 and the 1 of the following month
Edit : preventing R error

Comment: Half a month is not well defined

Comment: Please include a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: i tried to clarify in the edit

Comment: What is your expected output for given `dateseq` ? It is not exactly clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: The ouput should be an increasing date series starting at the 15. of a giving month than jumping to the first of the following month than to the 15. and so on

Comment: check for example the package padr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my solution without a loop:

```
library(lubridate)

dateseq <- seq(from = ymd_hms("2016-11-01_3-50-23"),
               length.out = 15, by = "months")

day(dateseq) <- rep(c(1,15), length(dateseq)/2+1)[1:length(dateseq)]

dateseq
```

This gives alternating one month starting 1st, the next the 15th.

Based on your comment I'm not sure if what you need is each month once starting 1st and once the 15th. In this case this should work:

```
dateseq <- sort(rep(seq(from = ymd_hms("2016-11-01_3-50-23"),
                        length.out = 15, by = "months"),
                    2))

day(dateseq) <- rep(c(1,15), length(dateseq)/2+1)[1:length(dateseq)]

dateseq
```